# ftp://username:password@domain "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ftp

I am trying to use a single command to login to ftp (as a program requires it)

```
ftp://username:password@domain
```

returns

> "No such file or directory"

What do I need for this command to work? Is it from legacy systems or something? I can do the whole

```
ftp servername
ftp>username
ftp>password
```

But that is not what I am looking for.

Debian 7.8.0

Answer (score 0):

full command should look like this:

```
ftp ftp://username:password@domain
```